# Is every simply connected set in the plane regular for Brownian motion?

Tags: probability-theory, brownian-motion

### Background

Let $\{B_t\}_{t\ge 0}$ be Brownian motion in $\mathbb R^d$. For $D\subset\mathbb R^d$, let $\tau_D=\inf\{t>0:B_t\in D\}$ be the hitting time of $D$ for $B_t$. For $D\subset\mathbb R^d$ open, a point $x\in\partial D$ is said to be *regular* if $\mathbb P_x(\tau_{D^c}=0)=1$; that is, if when the Brownian motion is started from $x$ it hits $D^c$ instantaneously (possibly by returning to $x$). An open set $D$ is said to be *regular* if all of its boundary points are.

### Motivation

If $d=1$, every set is regular because for any $\varepsilon>0$ the Brownian motion $B_t$ will return to its starting point at infinitely many $t$ in the interval $(0,\varepsilon)$.

If $d\ge 2$, I believe the unit ball $\mathbb B=\{x\in\mathbb R^d:|x|<1\}$ is regular and simply connected, the annulus $\mathbb A=\{x\in\mathbb R^d:1<|x|<2\}$ is regular but not simply connected, and the punctured ball $\mathbb B\setminus\{0\}$ is neither.

If $d\ge 3$, then I believe $\mathbb B\setminus\left([0,1)\times\{0\}^{d-1}\right)$ should not be regular, because e.g. the second two coordinates of the Brownian motion will both be zero concurrently with probability zero.

However, when $d=2$ I haven't been able to think of an open set which is simply connected but not regular. If we look at $\mathbb B\setminus\left([0,1)\times\{0\}\right)$ again, this time I don't think it works. In response to the comments, we'll look at what's going on here more carefully. Let $B_t=(B^1_t,B^2_t)$.

For boundary points $(a,0)$ with $0<a<1$, as $\varepsilon\to0$ the probability that $B_t^1\in(0,1)$ for all times $t\in(0,\varepsilon)$ approaches one by continuity of probability and continuity of Brownian motion. And conditional on the event $\{\forall t\in(0,\varepsilon), B_t^1\in(0,1)\}$ the probability that $B_t$ hits the boundary at some point in $(0,\varepsilon)$ is one, since $B_t^2$ is zero for infinitely many $t\in(0,\varepsilon)$ with probability one.

So the only possible irregular boundary point of $\mathbb B\setminus\left([0,1)\times\{0\}\right)$ is $(0,0)$. Here I don't have a proof of regularity, just a heuristic. Namely, $B_t^2$ will be zero at infinitely many times on the interval $(0,\varepsilon)$, and because $B^1$ and $B^2$ are independent I expect that "half" of those times the first coordinate will be non-negative.

### Question

Is every simply connected open subset of $\mathbb R^2$ regular, or is there an counterexample that I'm not thinking of?

Comment: I think that in your example $\mathbb B\setminus\left([0,1)\times\{0\}\right)$ points on $[0,1)\times\{0\}$ are not regular. Second coordinate of Brownian motion starting from those points immediately $>$ or $<0$.

Comment: @NikitaEvseev The second coordinate will be immediately $>$ or $<0$, but it will also immediately be zero. I edited the question to make it more clear why I think $\mathbb B\setminus\left([0,1)\times\{0\}\right)$ is regular.

Answer (score 3):

The regularity of every boundary point of an open set in $\mathbb R^2$ is in fact
strongly related to connectedness. However, that's more a property of the complement of the set:

Problem 4.2.16 in [1] which is:

*Let $D\subset\mathbb R^2$ be open, and suppose that $a\in\partial D$ has the property that there exists a point $b\not=a$ in $\mathbb R^2\setminus D\,,$ and a simple arc in $\mathbb R^2\setminus D$ connecting $a$ to $b\,.$ Show that $a$ is regular.*

The solution is provided in [1] section 4.5.

The unit disc minus the line segment $[0,1)\times\{0\}$ clearly satisfies the properties of $D$ in that problem.

[1] I. Karatzas, S. Shreve, *Brownian Motion and Stochastic Calculus.*

Comment: This is nice because it narrows down the form that a possible counterexample can take, though strictly speaking it's not an answer to the question (unless you are claiming that every simply connected set satisfies the properties of $D$ in that problem). Still, +1.

Comment: @A.Howells . Does it not ? See my edit.

Comment: Probably I'm being dense, but I still don't see it. It is clear to me the complement of an open simply connected set $D$ in the plane cannot contain isolated points (that is, points $a$ such that some neighborhood of $a$ intersects $D^c$ only at $a$). But what we need is the seemingly stronger property that, given any $a\in D^c$, one can find a $b\in D^c$ distinct from $a$ and a simple arc in $D^c$ connecting $a$ to $b$.

Comment: @A.Howells . The answer of Anton Petrunin to [this question](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/210706/when-is-the-boundary-of-an-open-planar-set-a-jordan-curve) shows that there might be a gap still. However, does he give a proof? I have no idea what a pseudo-arc is .

Comment: I hadn't heard of a pseudo-arc before today either, but funny enough right after I saw your first edit I asked a friend IRL, and he also linked me to the Wikipedia article for the pseudo-arc. I don't yet understand the idea well enough to say anything helpful. Perhaps it's time for another question.... In the meantime, it might be good to edit your post to retract the claim that the answer is yes, since it seems we are not yet sure.

Comment: Rolled back. Your question turns more and more into an interesting problem.

Comment: In a shameless act of self-promotion, I'm going to link to my own paper which proves something equivalent to this: https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S0022247X18303433

Comment: @user387394 . Nice. If I understand correctly Bass (1995) shows that the answer to OP's question is yes, and you used another method to show it differently.

Comment: @Kurt G. Yes, that's correct.